# how to install svn on ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn

how to install an svn client in ubuntu 11.04 ?
step by step please?

am new to this,I got used with windows tortoise svn gui client
thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have root access, this is actually pretty easy.

In the most basic form, just run the following in a terminal as root:

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

If you want to do more, have a look at the server guide's section on Subversion:

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/subversion.html

Answer (score 1):

Open up a Terminal (using Unity) and then type in:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

Now, you can type `svn`.  If you're not familiar with the command-line, you will want to research that separately.

Comment: does it have a "man svn" via terminal after installation?

Comment: @sasori: No, the documentation of svn is in the command itself, use `svn help` and `svn subcommand --help` to read quick manual, in-depth are on the project's website.

Answer (score 1):

You can install subversion using `apt-get install` as you do normally with any other package. However, it is useful to think about using SVN + WebDAV (via apache). [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion) explains how to install subversion and access it using several protocols.

Comment: does it have a "man svn" via terminal after installation?

Comment: You will install subversion as normal, but you can create multiple ways of accessing it. For example, it can be accessed via HTTP or SSH, etc.. The provided link should explain this to you.